# Loops and Vector for generating URLs; digits in loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I want to produce a vector of URLS that correspond to each day of the year, however can't seem to figure out two things: i) I would like to produce one vector of urls with all of the dates but keep getting a matrix that produces one vector for each month (a vector length 372 rather than 12 columns of 31); and ii) I would like to have the single digits concatenate with 0, so that instead of 1,2,3 I get 01,02,03. Code below and many thanks to all responses.

```
n <- 12
q <- 31
url_vec <- matrix(NA, ncol = 1, nrow = q)
full_url_vec <- as.data.frame(rep(NA, q)) 

for(j in 1:n){

            url_year <- paste("http://www.parliament.go.ug/hansard/hans_view_date.jsp?dateYYYY=2009&dateMM=", j, "&dateDD=", sep = "")                      
        for(i in 1:q){
        url <-  paste(url_year, "&dateDD=", i, sep = "")
        url_vec[i,] <- url          
    }

full_url_vec[,j] <- url_vec

}

dim(full_url_vec)
full_url_vec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach: Use `sprintf` in conjunction with `paste`. The key here is to make sure that your month vector (`j`) cycles appropriately, so for that, I used `rep`.

```
j <- rep(sprintf("%02d", 1:12), each = 31)
i <- sprintf("%02d", 1:31)
url_year <- paste("http://some/siteMM=", j, "&dateDD=", i, sep = "")
length(url_year)
# [1] 372
head(url_year)
# [1] "http://some/siteMM=01&dateDD=01" "http://some/siteMM=01&dateDD=02"
# [3] "http://some/siteMM=01&dateDD=03" "http://some/siteMM=01&dateDD=04"
# [5] "http://some/siteMM=01&dateDD=05" "http://some/siteMM=01&dateDD=06"
tail(url_year)
# [1] "http://some/siteMM=12&dateDD=26" "http://some/siteMM=12&dateDD=27"
# [3] "http://some/siteMM=12&dateDD=28" "http://some/siteMM=12&dateDD=29"
# [5] "http://some/siteMM=12&dateDD=30" "http://some/siteMM=12&dateDD=31"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help - that's fantastic and so much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You dont even need a loop.  `paste` is vectorized
*Also, `paste0` saves you the step of using `sep=""`*

```
i <- 1:31

urlBase  <- "http://yourwebiste.com/?dfdfsdfdfd."
urlSuffix <- "apikey=d323j43k43"

paste0(urlBase, i, urlSuffix)
```

---

as far as concatenating with `0`'s, here is a function, `fw0()` on github that does that: 
LINK: https://github.com/rsaporta/pubR/blob/gitbranch/fw0.R